# iOS 11 Custom UIAlertView not rendering fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiactionsheet

So I have and app that has a custom UIAlertView (by custom I mean adding the UILabel at the bottom programatically). It works just fine on iOS < 11, but in iOS 11 it fails miserably. So, on iOS 10 it works fine (left) but it fails in iOS 11 (right) with the same code of course[image: iOS 10 vs iOS 11]

And this is the code that I am using to make the custom UAlertView. Any ideas?

```
SessionManager *sessionMgr = [SessionManager sharedManager];
NSString *saludoStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"¡Bienvenido %@!",self.datosPersonalesResponse.nombre];
NSString *mailStr = [sessionMgr getUserEmail];
NSString *mensajeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Te hemos enviado un email de \nactivación de cuenta a: \n\n%@\n\nActivá tu cuenta para recibir alertas,\n avisos recomendados y postularte a \nempleos.\n",mailStr];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:saludoStr message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cerrar" otherButtonTitles:@"No lo recibí", nil];
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
lbl.numberOfLines= 0;

[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:13]];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:146/255.0f green:146/255.0f blue:146/255.0f alpha:1.0]];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mensajeStr];
[attributedStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                      value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:16]
                      range:NSMakeRange(56,[mailStr length])];

[attributedStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(56,[mailStr length])];

lbl.attributedText = attributedStr;
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[alert setValue:lbl forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

Comment: `UIAlertView` has never supported the ability to add custom views. It may have worked in the past but the documentation has always stated not to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UIAlertView** is deprecated. Please consider using **UIAlertController** with [full details here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller).

Comment: This is comment, not an answer.

Comment: An answer is not necessarily a solution but I can delete it if it bother you.